# Multiple javascript upload buttons only putting content in one

Tags: javascript, upload, haml, image-uploading, imagebutton

I'm trying to make two upload buttons. One is for an account logo.

```
          .col-sm-6
            .wrapper
              Account Logo
              #account_logo
                = image_tag @account.logo.url, :class => 'account_logo'
                = file_field_tag 'account[logo]', :accept => 'image/png,image/jpeg'
                %a.btn.btn-default{:href => '#'} Choose file
                %span.notice
                  Only PNG or JPG please.
```

The other is for an email logo.

```
          .col-sm-6
            .wrapper
              Email Logo
              #email_logo
                = image_tag @account.email_logo.url, :class => 'email_logo'
                = file_field_tag 'account[email_logo]', :accept => 'image/png,image/jpeg'
                %a.btn.btn-default{:href => '#'} Choose file
                %span.notice
                  Only PNG or JPG please.
```

I've added javascript so it works for both. However, there is something very wrong going on. I've added alerts to try and debug and they tell me that it's all going into #email_logo even when I click on the #account_logo button. Can some javascript wizard please help me?

```
              :javascript
                var logo = ["#account_logo", "#email_logo"];

                for (var i = 0; i < logo.length; i++) {
                  var on_change = (logo[i] + ' input[type=file]');
                  var on_click = (logo[i] + ' a.btn');
                  var logo_img = (logo[i] + ' img');

                  $(document).on('click', on_click , function() {
                    alert("it is now " + on_click);
                    $(on_change).click();
                    alert("it is now " + on_change);
                  });
                  $(document).on('change', on_change, function() {
                    alert("it is now " + on_change);
                    var filelist = $(this).get(0).files;
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                      var url = e.target.result;
                      alert("it is now " + logo_img);
                      $(logo_img).attr('src', url);
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL(filelist[0]);
                  });
                }
```

Comment: I suspect the code "reader.readAsDataURL(filelist[0]);" which on third line from end of your javascript program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because you are using a `for(var i = ...) {}` loop construct instead of `logo.forEach(function(element) { ... })`.

The reason this might be happening is because JavaScript does not have block scoping but function scoping, which means your loop variable `i` is available in the entire function, and your `.on('change', ...)` handlers will refer to this `i` as a variable, not as whatever value that variable had when you registered the handler.

Try using a `logo.forEach(function(element) { ... }` construct, and instead of setting `var on_change = (logo[i] + 'input[type=file]');`, do `var on_change = (element + 'input[type=file]');`.

Comment: Thanks! The scope thing was the problem.

I changed all my `logo[i]` to `element` and changed my for loop to `logo.forEach(function(element)` and it works.

Comment: Since I assume your backend is in ruby (because of the haml tag), maybe I should also mention that the `for` construct in ruby also does *not* introduce a new scope, very much like the `for` construct in javascript, so `for` loops can actually lead to "interesting" problems in ruby as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**:

Ah ha, @Frost found the problem - variable scope. I would have used an iterator myself, and missed here the effect scope would have on event binding.

Given you're already using jQuery, and are probably after much better browser compatibility than `forEach` provides, I would highly recommend using the `jQuery.each` function. You may as well also inline the logos array, and pass the click event directly too, giving:

```
$(["#account_logo",  "#email_logo"]).each(function(logo) {
    $(logo + " input[type=file]").on("click", $(logo + " a.btn").click);
    // etc.
});
```

---

**Original response**:

This seems like a lot of code for not much problem description. Are you saying that the event handlers are both applied to `#email_logo`, or that both buttons do the action desired of `#email_logo`? I haven't done file upload before, but from a quick review, the logic looks fine.

It would be easier to see the issue if you used `console.log` rather than `alert`, and pasted the results here, along with a description of how the log was produced.

I would prefer to comment this, but I don't have enough reputation.